# Teradata, Find Root Table from layers of Views

Tags: sql, teradata

I have to access thousands of views, and I need to figure out the original table for a view. Underneath each view, there are multiple other views prior to getting to the root table.

Is there a way to find the root table without having to do show view, show view, and finally show table?

Is this possible with a recursive query?

Comment: `show select from myview` returns DDL of all objects accessed by that Select.

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth! ```show  select * from myview``` works. Is there a way to parse to only return the table name? If not, I could script it to export each time to a text file and parse it there, but checking if I could do it in SQL.

Comment: If QueryLog is enabled on object level (to save space using NO COLUMNS option) it logs table/view info in `dbc.QryLogObjectsV.ObjectType`. Either query existing data or let the DBA enable it only for a specific user/accout and then run those SHOWs (Show is recorded, but not Explain)